# Unable to see logs in "show logging"

Tags: cisco

I'm unable to see any new logs about from Mar 8 in Cisco Nexus C9372PX
my logging configuration is as follows:

```
CORENEXUS02# show logging 

Logging console:                enabled (Severity: critical)
Logging monitor:                enabled (Severity: notifications)
Logging linecard:               enabled (Severity: notifications)
Logging timestamp:              Seconds
Logging source-interface :      enabled (Interface: loopback11)
Logging server:                 enabled
{10.22.34.116}
        server severity:        notifications
        server facility:        local7
        server VRF:             lan
        server port:            5560
Logging logflash:               enabled (Severity: notifications)
Logging logfile:                enabled

CORENEXUS02# show  running-config | include logging
logging level snmpd 3
ntp logging
logging server 10.22.34.116 5 port 5560 use-vrf lan
logging source-interface loopback11
```

No logs are sent to syslog or shown is in show logging.

Seems like the logging process is stopped or not working at all.
What can i do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Seems good.
Try to set Informational level and check it.
And question not related with Your problem, what Syslog server You use?

Comment: is there any single command to enable logging level informational ? We're using Kibana's somewhat logging plugin.

Comment: Which vrf is the loopback1 interface configured to use? Since you specify using the `lan` vrf in the logging server config, the source interface also needs to be part of that vrf.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using NX-OS, and at least some of the replies assume IOS.

One thing that's not related to your question... you're calling this a "core" nexus.  I assume that means N7k or 9500.  Does a 9500 support VDCs?  At least the 7k does, and it's recommended to create an "admin" VDC.  That admin VDC is where wou configure NTP; it seems like NTP is configured within a production VDC.

Anyway, back to the question at hand:

Looking at your output, it seems like you're only logging the SNMPd process.  There's a decent chance there's just nothing to log.

Also, are you sure you're sending your logging traffic to the correct VRF?  You've used VRF "lan" - is it setup correctly?

This is my (working) configuration on my Nexus 7010.  I've redacted the router name and the IPs, but you get the idea.

```
N7k# sh run all | inc ^logging
logging message interface type ethernet description
logging event link-status default
logging event trunk-status default
logging event link-status enable
logging event trunk-status enable
logging server [redacted] 7 use-vrf management facility local4
logging source-interface loopback0
logging monitor 5
N7k#
N7k#
N7k# sh run vrf management

!Command: show running-config vrf management
!Time: Mon Dec 16 14:42:25 2019

version 7.3(3)D1(1)

interface mgmt0
  vrf member management
vrf context management
  ip route 0.0.0.0/0 [redacted]

N7k# 
N7k# 
N7k# 
N7k# sh run int lo0

!Command: show running-config interface loopback0
!Time: Mon Dec 16 14:43:45 2019

version 7.3(3)D1(1)

interface loopback0
  ip address [redacted]/32
  ipv6 address [redacted]/128

N7k#
N7k# sh logg last 5
2019 Dec 16 14:44:01 N7k %L2FM-2-L2FM_CONTINUOUS_MAC_MOVE: Mac Address (0050.569e.214d) in Vlan 1210 is moving continuously
2019 Dec 16 14:44:43 N7k %L2FM-2-L2FM_CONTINUOUS_MAC_MOVE: Mac Address (0050.569e.789d) in Vlan 1210 is moving continuously
2019 Dec 16 14:45:41 N7k %L2FM-2-L2FM_CONTINUOUS_MAC_MOVE: Mac Address (0050.568b.7bd2) in Vlan 1204 is moving continuously
2019 Dec 16 14:46:43 N7k %L2FM-2-L2FM_CONTINUOUS_MAC_MOVE: Mac Address (0050.56b5.02f4) in Vlan 1204 is moving continuously
2019 Dec 16 14:46:55 N7k %L2FM-2-L2FM_CONTINUOUS_MAC_MOVE: Mac Address (0050.569e.1507) in Vlan 1225 is moving continuously
N7k#
```

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarifying questions.  Comments (like this) are for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a **show system internal flash** to view how much space you have left internally. When the system fills its logs to 100% it is unable to perform any logging function. My recommendation would be to turn off logging on the device and log to a syslog server only.

Comment: thanks, but there're no such command: (config)# logging on                           ^
% Invalid command at '^' marker.

Comment: can you do a 'show logging module' or 'show logging info' anything like that?

Comment: I also found this and it might be helpful - https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/nexus-7000-series-switches/116427-technote-product-00.html

Comment: show system internal flash shows: `none               51200  51200         0 100% /var/volatile/log` seems like it's used 100%. Strange, why that file doesnt overwrites with newer logs ?  Added full paste here: https://pastebin.com/DwRYx6bk
`

Comment: cool, so clear the logfile and you should be all good again.

Comment: use - 'no logging logfile' - you could just turn logging off locally on the device, is you have it going to a syslog server anyway - this should stop it running out of space and keep you logging

Comment: @CrazyHorse019  You should edit your answer (or create a new one) with the correct diagnosis and fix.  That way, others can benefit from your answer.

Comment: thanks, but as i see it's not fixed completely. As i cleared the wtmp file in bash shell with: cat /dev/null > /var/log/wtmp , i started to see some logs appearing to the screen. But i dont see anything in show logging. I need to see logs in the device itself also. Any ideas how to fix it fully ? Show logging says that logging to file is enabled. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

logging server xx.xx.xx.xx 6 use-vrf default

Comment: xx.xx.xx.xx Your syslog server